# How to fix "DownloadURL gives responseXML null value"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am developing a web UI and using dynamic downloadURl method to get the output and a php(testing.php) file and process it further, the php file gives a valid xml file output but in downloadURl function it gives responseXML=null error.
Sometimes the UI is able to get the response XML but most of the time it returns null value.

Here is my downloadURl file code

```
  downloadUrl("testing.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("Chainage");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                   var temperkey = markers[i].getAttribute("temperkey");
                  var vibration = markers[i].getAttribute("vibration");
                  var batterystatus = markers[i].getAttribute("batterystatus");
                  var lt = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
                  var lg = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");

          var status = markers[i].getAttribute("status");

          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>"+'Chainage:'+"</b>"+"<b>"+ name + "</b> <br/>"+"<b>"+'LAT:'+"</b>"+"<b>"+ lt + "</b> <br/>"+"<b>"+'LONG:'+"</b>"+"<b>"+ lg + "</b> <br/>"+"<b>"+'EcbNo:'+"</b>"+'<a id="ancid" href="#" onclick="return check()">'+address+'</a>';
    var icon = customIcons[status] || {};
                  var img1='12.png';
                 if(status==1)
                        {
                           img1='13.png';
                                //var  img2='Phonehandset.gif';
                        }
                  if(temperkey==1||vibration==1)
                        {
                           img1='14.png';
                           //img1='Phonehandset.gif';
                    }
                  if(Number==address)
                        {

                                img1='Phonehandset.gif';
                                clearInterval(myinterval);

                        }
                  if(batterystatus==1)
                        {
                           img1='11.png';
                        }
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon:img1,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
          }, 4000);
```

my testing.php file output is given below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ecb_config><marker Chainage="Police Bhavan,Vadodara" address="1005" status="1" lat="22.3016" lng="73.1933" temperkey="0" vibration="0" batterystatus="1"/><marker Chainage="" address="1001" status="1" lat="" lng="" temperkey="0" vibration="0" batterystatus="1"/><marker Chainage="20(Vadora)" address="1006" status="0" lat="18.35452552912664" lng="76.11328125" temperkey="0" vibration="0" batterystatus="0"/><marker Chainage="" address="1003" status="0" lat="" lng="" temperkey="" vibration="0" batterystatus=""/><marker Chainage="" address="1002" status="1" lat="18.5590" lng="73.7868" temperkey="0" vibration="0" batterystatus=""/></ecb_config>
```

In google chrome console, it gives the following error.

```
NewPhone.php:4469 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
    at NewPhone.php:4469
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (NewPhone.php:4532)
(anonymous) @ NewPhone.php:4469
request.onreadystatechange @ NewPhone.php:4532
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
downloadUrl @ NewPhone.php:4536
(anonymous) @ NewPhone.php:4466
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first to validate data

```
if(xml.documentElement.nodeName!==null)
```

Comment: Hi,  this Does stop giving me errors but it doesn't really solve my problem. The 'testing.php' file makes the document by taking data from mysql database so it should not be null at all. and My 'console.log' shows it is null. If there is any way to make sure it is not null at all , it would help a lot. Thanks for your advice .

Comment: I would write it that way first: let temperkey = markers[i].getAttribute("temperkey") || "";

Comment: Hi, This gives the same issue as above, It stops giving error. But it should be null in the first place